# Resize of block for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a div resizeable in width, this works fine, but when I add more of the same divs, the others are not resizeable.
How can I make sure all divs are resizeable in the same way?
Can someone help me with this problem?
This is what I have now:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('test');


  
   
    p.className = p.className + ' resizable';
    var resizer = document.createElement('div');
    resizer.className = 'resizer';
    p.appendChild(resizer);
    resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag, false);
    
    var resizerleft = document.createElement('div');
    resizerleft.className = 'resizerleft';
    p.appendChild(resizerleft);
    resizerleft.addEventListener('mousedown', initDragleft, false);

var startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

function initDrag(e) {
   startX = e.clientX;
   startY = e.clientY;
   startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p).width, 10);
   startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p).height, 10);
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
}

function doDrag(e) {
   p.style.width = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px';
}

function stopDrag(e) {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
}

var startX1, startY1, startmargin, startw;

function initDragleft(e) {
   startX1 = e.clientX;
   startY1 = e.clientY;
   startw = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p).width, 10);
   startmargin = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p).marginLeft, 10);
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', doDragleft, false);
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragleft, false);
}

function doDragleft(e) {
   p.style.marginLeft = (startmargin + e.clientX - startX1) + 'px';
   var newwidth = startmargin - (startmargin + e.clientX - startX1);
   p.style.width = (startw + newwidth ) + 'px';
}

function stopDragleft(e) {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', doDragleft, false);    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragleft, false);
}
```

```css
p { background: lime; height: 200px; width: 300px; margin-left:100px; }
p.resizable { background: cyan; position: relative; }
p .resizer { width: 10px; height: 100%; background: blue; position:absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; cursor: se-resize; }

p .resizerleft { width: 10px; height: 100%; background: blue; position:absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; cursor: se-resize; }
```

```html
<p id="test">Click to make me resizable</p>
```

I tried to add `e.target.parentElement` instead of `p`, but that makes the resize less smoothly somehow.
Pleasse help me!

Comment: Can you show an example of when you add more resisable elemnts? In your Js code, you select the element with its ID and that selection method only selects one element.

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, likely you are violating this basic rule, when you create more than one of those “divs” (which are actually _paragraphs_.)